# Real Time/Historical weather data

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies, historical-data, historical

I am looking to incorporate weather data into my algorithmic models. What is a good source to find historical + real time weather data by zipcode or region? Any help will be appreciated! Preferably an API

Comment: You might check NOAA's National Centers for Environmental Information at http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/

Comment: Should be community wiki due to no definitive answer